# Problems with foreign keys on delete

Tags: java, sqlite

I've two tables that has defined as below; From user table, hospitalId and poliklinikId both references table relhospol, and if any row is deleted from relhospol, (if any user is related with it), I want to set the hospitalId and poliklinikId null, DDL says that. When i delete a row from SQLite Manager it nulls the User's hospitalId and PoliklinikId, However when i try to remove a row from application level (Java), it only removes from relhospol, it does not set null (hospitalId, PoliklinikId) What is the missing point ? 
JDBC Driver: SQLite-jdbc-3.7.2

```
CREATE TABLE [USER] (
  [ID] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [GROUPID] INTEGER CONSTRAINT [FK_USER_GID] REFERENCES [GROUP]([ID]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  [HOSPITALID] INTEGER, 
  [POLIKLINIKID] INTEGER, 
  [NAME] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  [LOGINID] VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
  [EMAIL] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  [PASSWORD] VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT [FK_USER_RELHOSPOL] FOREIGN KEY([HOSPITALID], [POLIKLINIKID]) REFERENCES [RELHOSPOL]([HOSPITALID], [POLIKLINIKID]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [AS] ON [USER] ([LOGINID]);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [AS1] ON [USER] ([EMAIL]));

CREATE TABLE [RELHOSPOL] (
  [HOSPITALID] INTEGER CONSTRAINT [FK_RELHOSPOL_HOS] REFERENCES [HOSPITAL]([ID]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  [POLIKLINIKID] INTEGER CONSTRAINT [FK_RELHOSPOL_POL] REFERENCES [POLIKLINIK]([ID]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_RELHOSPOL_1] PRIMARY KEY ([HOSPITALID], [POLIKLINIKID]));
```

Comment: Any idea? Is there any problem with DDL ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set NULL a primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE [RELHOSPOL] (
[HOSPITALID] INTEGER CONSTRAINT [FK_RELHOSPOL_HOS] REFERENCES [HOSPITAL]([ID]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
[POLIKLINIKID] INTEGER CONSTRAINT [FK_RELHOSPOL_POL] REFERENCES [POLIKLINIK]([ID]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_RELHOSPOL_1] PRIMARY KEY ([HOSPITALID], [POLIKLINIKID]));
```

You are trying to remove a row from which table? Can you post the DELETE SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've changed the RELHOSPOL's definition as below; When i delete row from RELHOSPOL from the SQL Manager with executing a DELETE command, it nulls the necessary rows at the USER table. Whenever I delete a row from application with the method written below, it only deletes row from RELHOSPOL, and does not SET NULL the necessary rows at USER table

```
CREATE TABLE [RELHOSPOL] (
  [ID] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [HOSPITALID] INTEGER, 
  [POLIKLINIKID] INTEGER);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UNIQUE_RELHOSPOL] ON [RELHOSPOL] ([HOSPITALID], [POLIKLINIKID]);
```

Delete Method is :

```
public void deletePoliklinikFromHospital(int hospitalId, int poliklinikId) throws SQLException{
        String query = "DELETE FROM [RELHOSPOL] WHERE (HOSPITALID = ? AND POLIKLINIKID = ?)";
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = db.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setInt(1, hospitalId);
            statement.setInt(2, poliklinikId);
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a guess, but maybe you are not aware, that you have to [enable foreign key support](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` everytime you connect to the database? If this is not done, your statements will be parsed, but not enforced. This could explain, why it is working from SQLite Manager.

One should also be aware, that old versions of Sqlite (<3.6.19) will tolerate the syntax but too will not enforce anything.

As sidenote:
As @Neuquino writes the `ON DELETE SET NULL` statements for table `RELHOSPOL` don't seem to make sense.